# bash script to create folders and move files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have many files created from a simulation.
Like this:  res_00001.root through res_09999.root.

I would like to create a series of folders that move in batches of 1000 files in sequence to a newly created folder based on the filename we are moving.  e.g. folder1 would contain res_00001.root through res_00999.root, folder2 res_01000.root through res_01999.root, ...

I attempted to create a script but it's not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
N_files=$1
for (( file=0; file<$N_files; ++file )) do #state what file I am looking at
  s=file%1000 INPUT=printf data/output_%04lu.root $file` OUTPUT=printf data/folder%02lu/res_%04lu.root $s # move the files
  mv INPUT OUTPUT
done`
```

I've been banging my head against this for sometime, I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please show us exactly what you have tried rather than links to your reading material

Comment: SO is not a codewritting service, provide the faulty/non working code so we can help you sort it out.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
    N_files=$1
    for (( file=0; file<$N_files; ++file ))
    do
     #state what file I am looking at
     s=i%1000
    INPUT=`printf data/output_%04lu.root $file` 
    OUTPUT=`printf data/folder%02lu/res_%04lu.root $s`

    # move the files
    mv INPUT OUTPUT
  
    done`

Comment: Sorry about that, bad formatting.

Comment: You may want to edit the answer and put the code ([MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can run this little script if you can't find the `rename` program - make backup first!

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
for f in *.root; do
   n=$(tr -dc '[0-9]' <<< $f)
   ((d=(10#$n/1000)+1))
   [ ! -d folder$d ] && mkdir folder$d
   echo mv "$f" folder$d/$f
done
```

**Original Answer**

Make a backup and see if this helps you on a copy of a small subset of your files:

```
rename --dry-run 's/[^0-9]//g; my $d=int($_/1000)+1; $_="folder$d/res_$_.root"' *root
```

**Sample Output**

```
'res_00001.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00001.root'
'res_00002.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00002.root'
'res_00003.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00003.root'
'res_00004.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00004.root'
'res_00005.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00005.root'
...
...
'res_00997.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00997.root'
'res_00998.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00998.root'
'res_00999.root' would be renamed to 'folder1/res_00999.root'
'res_01000.root' would be renamed to 'folder2/res_01000.root'
'res_01001.root' would be renamed to 'folder2/res_01001.root'
'res_01002.root' would be renamed to 'folder2/res_01002.root'
'res_01003.root' would be renamed to 'folder2/res_01003.root'
...
...
```

If it looks good, remove the `--dry-run` so it actually does stuff rather than just saying what stuff it *would* do!

- `s/[^0-9]//g` gets rid of anything non-numeric in the filename
- `my $d=int($_/1000)+1` calculates the directory name
- `$_="folder$d/res_$_.root"` builds the output filename

Comment: Thank you.  I ran this as a one-liner on the terminal but I don't see any folders being generated anywhere.  If I am in ../../data I expected to see data/folder1, data/folder2, etc..  It ran without comment but no folders were generated.  I did remove the --dry-run

Comment: I should also mention that I am running on Centos7 and it looks I have rename(1) with options -v verbose, -s symlink, -h help, -V Version.  I don't have the -n for dry-run.  I do not have sudo.

Comment: You can make the directories up-front yoursel with `mkdir folder{1..10}`. Not sure which package `rename` comes in on Centos - maybe `moreutils`. It is just a Perl script.

Comment: It's sometimes called `prename` ... Perl rename.

Comment: prename doesn't exist.  It doesn't dislike this command but it doesn't do anything on this machine.  I created folder1, folder2, .. The subset of files I am running this on is res_5000.root (padding changes so I updated s/[^0-8]//g) which should go into folder6 which I created.

Comment: Another clue: when I ran this an a empty folder, folder6 the output stated rename 's/[^0-8]//g; my $d=int($_/1000)+1; $_="folder$d/res_$_.root"' *root 
rename: not enough arguments